# recover partitions lost during installation

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, data-loss

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 over my Ubuntu 12.04 installation. I had divided my hard drive into three partitions but when I reinstalled without formatting the disk, it made a single partition and I lost all my data.

Is any way to recover my data?

Answer (score 0):

No problem may be you will be able to get them back by using scalpel. install it by using

`sudo apt-get install scalpel`

Refer this to know its working fully

> [Scalpel](http://www.tecmint.com/install-scalpel-a-filesystem-recovery-tool-to-recover-deleted-filesfolders-in-linux/)